# D3/React: Passing data to the Constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am new to React and all the example code I have looked at so far shows constructor(props).  I am trying to pass data `({data:{action:[action: "changed", timestamp: 12345678], ...}` but I am confused because I have never seen that syntax with constructor before.

```
class Graph extends Component {

    constructor({nodes}) {
    const times = d3.extent(nodes.action.map(action => {action.action}))
    const range = [50, 450]
    super({nodes})
    this.state = {nodes, times, range}
    }
```

Comment: You pass props to a component and access via constructor. Then drill into the prop to access object... Whats your question?

Comment: How do I use d3.extent() to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out why you're getting all the actions from data you're passing?

Comment: No. I am trying to figure out how to drill into data using d3.extent().

Comment: Drill in when user interacts with your charts or pass data thats deep in your data object?

Comment: Pass data that's deep in the data object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178654/discussion-between-paul-makhnovskiy-and-n6dyn).

Comment: All this hassle to try to get some dots on a screen, lol.